# laravel ajax $.ajax error 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: ajax, laravel

i am using ajax laravel i am trying to store the info but when i click on the submit button to store, the console returns an error 500 (Internal Server Error) on line that cocntains $.ajax
i don't know why i wrote everything correctly please help

and here is my code

my route

```
Route::resource('products',App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::class);
```

my form and ajax code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add new Product</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" id="productform">
            @csrf
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">image</label>
                <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        
        $('#productform').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var name = $("input[name='name']").val();
            var image = $("input[name='image']").val();
            var _token = $("input[name='token']").val();
            $.ajax({ //this is the consoles error line
                url:"/products",
                type : "POST",
                data:{
                    name:name,
                    image:image,
                    _token:'{!! csrf_token() !!}',
                },
                dataType:'json',
                success:function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

my controller store method

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    
         $file = $request->file('image');
         $file_name = time().'_'.$file->getClientOriginalName();

        $upload = move_uploaded_file($file_name,public_path('files/'));
        // $upload = $file->storeAs(public_path($path), $file_name, 'public');

         if($upload){
            $product = Product::insert([
                 'name'=>$request->name,
                 'image'=>$file_name,
             ]);
            }
            
        return response()->json($product);
}
```

Comment: Try commenting out `var _token = $("input[name='token']").val();`  - there's no input field with `name=token" in markup shown in your code

Comment: there is @cssrf
but i commenting it still gives an error

Comment: What's the exact error message? Can you provide some part of the error stack trace

Comment: how can i find the error message?

Comment: First look in the `storage/logs/laravel.log` file and scroll all the way down to the end of file then scroll up till you find the first timestamp like `[2022-05-30 18:01:43] local.ERROR: .....` followed by `[stacktrace]` on next line, everything below that is the stack trace of the last error

Answer (score 0):

You Have a **File** in your **request**, so your content-type should be
**multipart/form-data** not JSON

You Just Need To Add those parameters to your ajax

```
enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
processData: false,
contentType: false,
```